# Can't install Waffle on M1: 'assert.h' file not found

Tags: waffle

I'm trying to install Waffle on an M1 Mac.

Per documentation, after creating a fresh new project with `npx hardhat`, I use `npm` like this: `npm install --save-dev ethereum-waffle`

This is the result:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/gian/Developer/learning-playground/web3/hardhat-tutorial/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp-build
npm ERR! CC(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.6.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gian/Developer/learning-playground/web3/hardhat-tutorial/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gian/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.6.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/gian/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.6.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/gian/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.6.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/gian/Developer/learning-playground/web3/hardhat-tutorial/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../src/bufferutil.c:2:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
npm ERR! #include <assert.h>
npm ERR!          ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! 1 error generated.
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.3.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.6.0/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gian/Developer/learning-playground/web3/hardhat-tutorial/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/gian/.npm/_logs/2022-03-08T15_26_01_888Z-debug-0.log
```

Same outcome when downgrading to Node 16.14

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding these packages:

- gcc
- g++
- libc-dev
- musl
- musl-dev

In my case I also had to add (running it on a Node Alpine Docker container)

- python3
- make

Not entirely sure why these packages are needed, but I found this solution from [this issue](https://github.com/hobbyquaker/node-red-contrib-lgtv/issues/32#issuecomment-739316263).

Comment: Unfortunately many of those libs are not available on MacOS - only on Linux. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I know it's far from ideal, but what you can do is create a devcontainer (if you use VSCode) and run it from inside the container. Helps isolating a lot of these issues.